# search page with various jquery bells and whistles

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

a lot of webapps now a days use jquery widgets in their search pages to help the user filter down the search results without ever leaving the page.  Because of this I noticed that webapps are now starting to code tables/lists in `<ul>` code since its easy to append ajax data to it.

I'm curious to  now how a search page like airbnb's would work.  http://www.airbnb.com/search

they have a  list that is dynamically changed when the user makes changes to search options presented on the right hand navigation.

Can someone guide me to a tutorial that shows something like this?  I am trying to accomplish something like this in rails3 using jquery.  Any examples/github repos would help me.

Comment: Isn't the page you just linked an example? The are not serving minified JS files, so it should be pretty easy to read and step through their code.

Comment: the jquery code. but I won't get to see how they are handling it on the rails side.  Plus I thought if there was an example out there that showed it on a lower scale then i'd be able to comprehend it better. but yes you are correct, if nothing else I can find then parsing through that code will be an option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this site works internally, but i would it this way:

- Bind event listeners to the checkboxes/sliders/whatnot to call a single function:

  - This function would go through all elements (all checkboxes/sliders/etc).
  - If a given element is checked/edited (for instance you move a slider) the function add this element to ajax parameters
  - For instance, if you check the "Private Room" checkbox, do something like: `paramlist["PrivateRoom"] = "true"`
  - In the end, call an ajax function to your backend server with all parameters.
- On the ajax callback i would update the result panel with the results from the server.